# How to classify the extensions of $A_4$ by $Z / 2Z$?

Tags: group-theory, exact-sequence, group-extensions

I am looking for all groups $H$ that fit in to an exact sequence:

$0 \to Z/2Z \to H \to A_4 \to 1$, where here $A_4 \subset S_4$ are the even permutations.

I know two - there is one split extension, the direct product, and there is also the extension which is described by the action $SL(2,3)$ on $P^1_{F_3}$.

Are these all of them?

I am asking this because I want to understand what the cover in $SU(2)$ of the group of tetrahedral symmetries in $SO(3)$ is. I know in principle one can compute this directly, but I would like some direct explanation for the question posed above. (There is a unique element of order 2 in $SU(2)$, so this can be used to eliminate the trivial extension.)

I am also interested in this question in the situation where the groups on the right are $S_4$ and $A_5$, for the same reason.

Comment: Yes those are the only two possibilities. A brief explanation is that the Sylow $2$-subgroup of such an extension would have to admit an automorphism of order $3$, and the only possibilities are $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$ and $Q_8$. These give rise to the two extensions in question.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks. Let me think about the details. The only step that I don't see how to work on is to move from understanding the structure of the Sylow 2-subgroup of H to understanding H. It seems that then we are trying to solve the extension problem for $Sylow_2(H) \to H \to Z/3Z$. I don't see how this is in principle easier.

Comment: @DerekHolt Nevermind, I think I understanding - in that case it will split.